# VS 2015 RC build failed with no error

Tags: visual-studio-cordova

I am using VS 2015 and try to deploy android apps with Apache Cordova, Android SDK v24 installed and all the Enviroment variable Overrides are set correctly.
When I create a new project and Run it (with Ripple-Nexus S), in the output panel, this below message with no error is shown:

> =========Build:0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up to date, 0 skipped==========

anybody can help me

thanks...

Comment: Naser, the build output (View > Output) has detailed information about the fail. Please include it in your question. The build output will provide some information about the fail.

When you say Android SDK v24 do you mean Android SDK Tools r24?

Comment: hi here is the link that contain the Ouput Massage

Comment: Naser,  Unfortunately, the link doesn't work.  Can you edit your original post to include the output message?

Answer (score 3):

Try to change VS build output from minimal to diagnostic

Tools > Option > Projects and Solutions > Build and Run > MSBuild project build output verbosity.

This will help to get the exact error.

Comment: Thanks, this helps to find the root cause

Answer (score 1):

Many developers faces many problem while creating first cordova app in vs 2015 but common error is below
**Build:0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up to date, 0 skipped**

The main cause of this error is missing required plugin for develop cordova app.
First of all to check all plugins/components whether is installed or not.

According to window 7
Go to Control Panel -> programs -> Programs and Features -> Right Click on Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2015 -> then Click on Change popup-> Expand Cross Platform Mobile Development-> verify all component should be checked, if all Plugins/Component are not checked please checked and click on update button.

[Click to view all components and plugins required to cordova mobile app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/akXXT.png)

I hope this article will be helpful

Answer (score 0):

I think the interesting part is here:

```
1>  'C:\Users\zohor\AppData\Roaming\npm\vs-tac-cli.cmd' is not recognized as an internal or external command, (TaskId:21)
1>  operable program or batch file. (TaskId:21)
1>Done executing task "MdaVsCli" -- FAILED. (TaskId:21)
```

You don't have the `vs-tac-cli.cmd` file in your Node.JS directory. I'd clear Cordova cache in Visual Studio (Options -> Tools for Apache Cordova -> Clear Cordova Cache) and then try again.

Comment: I Cleare Cordova Cache and when i rebuild the project, i see 17 error :